# How to optimize my MySQL query that takes more than 500 seconds

Tags: mysql, query-optimization

This is my MySQL query, I used LEFT JOIN:

```
SELECT ph.id, ph.number
FROM phone ph
LEFT JOIN linked_phones lp ON ph.number = lp.number
WHERE ph.userid = 10 and ph.active = 1 AND ph.linkid = 50 AND lp.number IS null
```

I want to select all the not linked numbers yet, but it takes so long to be executed (more than 500 seconds).
I added indexes on the two tables:

- first index on table phone: links_idx(userid, active, linkid )
- second index on table linked_phones: number_idx(number)

Here there are the results of EXPLAIN query:

| id | select_type | table | type | possible_keys | key | key_len | ref | rows | Extra |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | SIMPLE | ph | ref | links_idx | links_idx | 12 | const,const,const | 127935 |  |
| 1 | SIMPLE | al | ALL | name_idx,number_idx |  |  |  | 84355 | Range checked for each record (index map: 0xA); Not exists |

When I execute the first part only from the phone table:

```
select count(1)
from phone 
where userid = 10 and active=1 AND linkid =50
```

It gives the result quickly: more than 84506 rows

And when I execute the second part from the other table which is:

```
select count(1) from linked_phones where userid = 10
```

It also gives me the result quickly: 85149 rows

I have also tried to use sub-query but same issue:

```
select id, number
from phone
where userid = 10 and active =1 AND linkid = 50
and number not in (select number from linked_phones where);
```

I will be grateful for any suggestions to optimize this query.

Comment: Can you check that the datatypes of your 2 "number" columns match?

Comment: Your indices actually look fine _but_ why are you using `LIMIT` without `ORDER BY`?

Comment: @Solarflare yes I check and found out that the number from the phone table is `bigint(25)` but the number from the other table is `char(64)`, the issue is that I have no right to change those columns

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I have just added it to check if that would help and forgot to remove it sorry I update the query

Comment: @amel if you're able to create indexes on these tables, you should add `phone.number` in the multi-index as well. For this join to make sense, I assume, that all numbers are in an int-compatible format. In this case, you can also add an index on a casted value like that `CREATE INDEX idx_name ON linked_phones (CAST(number AS UNSIGNED));`

Comment: Oh, my my my.  A telephone number stored as a numeric data type. That is atrocious data design.

Comment: As already hinted, the mixed data types do not work. Basically because an integer "1" could match a string "    1abc", and MySQL has no good way of finding all possible entries like this using an index lookup. You need to ask someone to fix the types or to add a calculated column or to add a functional key as jabberwocky suggested. Or accept the slow execution speed.

Comment: Thanks a lot, @Solarflare I tested this on my local with aligned data types and it works perfectly

Answer (score 0):

The first query would benefit from

```
ph:  INDEX(userid, active, linkid, number,  id)
lp:  INDEX(number)
```

The second would probably run faster by using `NOT EXISTS`:

```
and  number not in (
        SELECT  number
            from  linked_phones where
```

-->

```
AND NOT EXISTS( SELECT 1 FROM linked_phones
                  WHERE number = phone.number )
```

(The same indexes apply.)

Comment: Thanks, @Rick, but still have an issue since the datatypes of the 2 "number" columns don't match, so I could fix this by aligning the data types

Comment: @amel - _Edit your Question to point out the datatype discrepancy_

Comment: And be sure to state which is which.  I think the answer depends on that.